# How to get the native windows Browse for folder dialog in AIR

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I am trying to get the original windows browse for folder dialog in a AIR application.
From the AS3 AIR docs the File class has only **browseForDirectory** witch gives me a **browseForFile** window only with the Select button instead of Open.
What I want is a window with only the hierarchy tree folders and buttons

is there any way I can do this?

Comment: What platform are you attempting this on? I know such a specific window exists on Windows, but I do not believe it exists on OS X. What you describe is how I remember normally selecting a directory. (I just tested in IntelliJ using "Open Directory..." and that is precisely what I got)

Comment: Platform specific code requires a native extension.

Comment: I don't understand your problem : you want to get a file reference to a folder ? so the dialog you have with browseForDirectory seem to be good... you just select the folder you want instead of open it to chose file inside no ?

Comment: @drkstr1 Not entirely true. AIR does provide some native functionality by default. You just don't have much control over it

Comment: It would be so much easier if I could attach some pictures, but I need  reputation 10 to do so. @Binou you are right on the money, but that opens a "complex" window to select a folder, very similar to open a file window, what I want is this one [link](https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/resources/docs/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Host_Configuration_and_Guest_Installation_Guide/images/9-BrowseToDirectory_win7.png), a "simpler" version of it.

Comment: I don't think you can change the window type. If you really want this type of window maybe you can try to make a native extension for this